# How to get redux, initialState

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am very new to redux and have a problem. I have a website and when I search for something on one page, then go to another page and then back to the first page, the redux store doesnt return to initial state. I can see in the store that the search is not gone. How do I fix this?

My reducer looks like this:

```
const initialState = {
  query: {
    range: {
      from: null,
      to: null,
    },
    search: null,
    status: null,
    orderBy: 'InvoiceDueDate desc',
  },
  page: 1,
};


export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RESET:
      return { ...initialState };
    case UPDATE_QUERY:
      return {
        ...state,
        query: {
          ...state.query,
          ...action.payload.updates,
        },
        page: 1,
      };
    case UPDATE_PAGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        page: action.payload.page,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: did you dispatched reset action when get back to first page ?

Comment: What is the lifecycle method that you have used to fetch the data? or to fire the **RESET** event

Comment: You should probably return a _copy_ of the initial state, e.g. `return {...initialState}`. It's either that, or the reset action does not hit your reducer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you manipulating the initialState in rest of reducer?

Comment: case UPDATE_QUERY:
      return {
        ...state,
        query: {
          ...state.query,
          ...action.payload.updates,
        },
        page: 1,
      };
    case UPDATE_PAGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        page: action.payload.page,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

Comment: Probably you are updating search state with UPDATE_QUERY right. ...action.payload.updates must be doing that.  I mean there should be "search" property inside of action.payload.updates. And reset returns same object it takes search property and returns that. You are not reseting it there. When you do that {...initialState} you are not getting search null. Because initialState and state shows same memory reference.They are same. So its search property is manipulated by your UPDATE_QUERY. It is not null anymore. Hope i am clear enough.

Comment: So how do I set it to null again? Which it obviously needs to be?

Comment: Can you try this one :
    case RESET:
      return { ...state,query: { ...query, search: null } };

Comment: Thanks, that works. But do you have any idea where the manipulation happens?

Comment: Yes your UPDATE_QUERY does that. You are manipulating state there and also initialState changes with it. Because as i said they show same place, they are same. You think you are getting first initialState which was null. But it is not anymore it is changed with your UPDATE_QUERY.

Comment: What do you mean ? You wanna use this state, so you have to manipulate and then reset it on first page with my method. If you dont manipulate it how will you use in another page ^^

Comment: I dont understand why initialState is manipulated and why I have to do this "case RESET: return { ...state,query: { ...query, search: null } }" insted of just return initalState. In other examples I have seen, they all just return initialState. It confuses me.

Comment: https://dev.to/krsgrnt/safely-copying-nested-objects-in-javascript-5fpi 
Can you check this site